# Build an array of objects with two key/value pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to build an array like this :

```
[{'test1': 't1',  'test2' :'t2'},  
 {'test3' :'t3', 'test4': 't4' },
 {'test5': 't5',  'test6' :'t6'},
 {'test7' :'t7' , 'test8': 't7' }]
```

It will be an array of objects.

The object will have always have **two** key/value pairs.
Key and values will be dynamic.

I have to loop through the object below to build the array:

[image]

In the end, I have got to build a table out of the array, which will look like this:
[image]

It has to be a 2-columns table, with the key and value.

HTML:

```
<table class="detailList" >
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="labelCol" scope="row"> <label>test1</label> </th>
            <td class="dataCol"> t1</td>
            <th class="labelCol" scope="row"> <label>test2</label> </th>
            <td class="dataCol"> t2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="labelCol" scope="row"> <label>test3</label> </th>
            <td class="dataCol"> t3</td>
            <th class="labelCol" scope="row"> <label>test4</label> </th>
            <td class="dataCol"> t4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="labelCol" scope="row"> <label>test5</label> </th>
            <td class="dataCol"> t5</td>
            <th class="labelCol" scope="row"> <label>test6</label> </th>
            <td class="dataCol"> t6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="labelCol" scope="row"> <label>test7</label> </th>
            <td class="dataCol"> t7</td>
            <th class="labelCol" scope="row"> <label>test8</label> </th>
            <td class="dataCol"> t7</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Where do the key names and values come from?

Comment: You usually use the same keys, just different Objects.

Comment: I have updated the question. Keys/values come from an object. I loop through it to build the array. My main concern here is how to restrict the key/value pair to **two** per object in the array. Please help.

Comment: This seems like an improper use of an array of objects. Generally, each object in the array would have the same keys (for the most part). If you're going to have every key have a different name, why not use one single object?

Comment: I'm really confused as to how you want this implemented.  Do you want a function that takes in one key and then ties it to both items?  Or do you want someone to need both keys to access the two values?

Comment: also, those key names are horrible. I would hate to have to work with that object. I would use nested objects like `{'total': {'modal_all_year': {'commission':'300.00', 'premium':'567.55'}}}` break it down so it's clear and easy to work with.

Comment: I do not decide on the names. It's the client's specification. Gotta abide by those _long_ names.

Comment: I need to build a table out of all this info. Two columns table. Readonly. With the key and the value.

Comment: What do you want the table to end up looking like, could you show us the generated html you envision for a few rows? That would help a lot

Comment: The raw html would be more helpful. Is that 4 columns? Lets see that HTML

Comment: @DelightedD0D I would too, but nested objects have their own headaches too. Disagree? (Assuming it's dynamic/unpredictable)

Comment: @vic to some degree yes, but in six months, after you've moved on to 3 other projects and you suddenly have to come back to some code you barely remember writing, it's good to have a solid well defined structure. For me, those long names are quite distracting, i'd rather drill down

Comment: OK, so is the actual requirement to take as input an object with however many properties, and display those properties in an HTML table with two key/value pairs per row? Is there any need to have the array of two-property objects you originally asked about, or was that just what you thought you needed to then get the final output HTML?

Comment: @N.B. actually, that's 4 columns, its just that 2 of your columns are headings instead of normal columns, but still 4 columns. One sec, making a fiddle for you

Comment: @nnnnnn, Yes for the 1st part. I did it with dummy data. It was working, but then I got stuck when it came to building it with the real data. Any better suggestion in terms of design/structure/coding/anything will be most welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Bruhhh, just try my stupid algorithm.

Comment: @Vic, just tried it. I got the array that I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: Still waiting for @DelightedD0D's fiddle though. It could help with the structure etc.

Comment: Bruh, just traverse through the keys and make a new row if columns count is 4. That way, you're not manipulating the actual data.

Comment: Thanks @Vic. At least I am now able to continue with the dev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would create that table:

#### [Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgLcndpf/20/)

```js
var testObject = {
  some_key: {
    key1: '1',
    key2: '2',
    key3: '3',
  }
};

var elements = [];
var last = null;
// loop over the keys in the object in question
$.each(testObject.some_key, function(key, value) {
  var item = '<th class="labelCol" scope="row"><label>' + key + '</label></th><td class="dataCol">' + value + '</td>';
  if (!last) { // if no last item, set this row to last dont add to the array of elements just yet, we need the other two columns first
    last = item;
  } else {
    // if we already have a last, add these two columns to it, then add it to our array of elements
    elements.push(last + item);
    last = null;
  }
});
if (last) {
  // at the end, if we still have a "last" hanging around, add two empty columns
  var item = '<th class="labelCol" scope="row"><label></label></th><td class="dataCol"></td>';
  elements.push(last + item);
}
// join the array wrapping each set of 4 columns with a tr
var rows = '<tr>' + elements.join('<tr></tr>') + '</tr>';

$('.detailList tbody').html(rows);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="detailList">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I will try that. Thanks.

Comment: Tried it. Works great! Thanks @DelightedD0D. Thanks to you as well Vic.

Comment: @Vic, talking to me?

Comment: @N.B. I think Vic was just be being cheeky, his way of saying "well, sure, if you want to fix the real problem" ;)

Answer (score 1):

What a crazy requirement. I like it. Here's my take on it. (Didn't test it)

```
var twoPairArray = []; //array to be returned
var twoPairObj = {}; //temp obj for manipulation
for(var key in targetObj) //target obj has the keys to be processed
{
    if(Object.keys(twoPairObj).length == 2) //does temp obj have enough keys?
    {
        twoPairArray.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(twoPairObj))); //sloppy clone of temp obj
        twoPairObj = {}; //reset the temp obj.
    }
    twoPairObj[key] = targetObj[key]; //temp obj being manipulated into this craziness
}
```

Comment: It's a crazy requirement because the OP is almost certainly using objects and arrays in the wrong manner. That's the problem we really need to address.

Comment: I agree. What kind of design would need an array of objects with a key limit of two. If there is such a design that requires this, it needs a redesign.

Comment: Thanks. Got the array that I wanted.

Comment: @N.B. the tricky bit is looping over the elements in such a way as to use two separate keys and values on each row of the resulting table. ;)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for helping.